# Using search terms with Biopython to return accession numbers

Tags: python, biopython

I am trying to use Biopython (Entrez) with search terms that will return the accession number (and not the GI*).

Here is a tiny excerpt of my code:

```
from Bio import Entrez

Entrez.email = 'myemailaddress'
search_phrase = 'Escherichia coli[organism]) AND (complete genome[keyword])'
handle = Entrez.esearch(db='nuccore', term=search_phrase, retmax=100, rettype='acc', retmode='text')
result = Entrez.read(handle)
handle.close()
gi_numbers = result['IdList']
print(gi_numbers)
```

> '745369752', '910228862', '187736741', '802098270', '802098269',
>   '802098267', '387610477', '544579032', '544574430', '215485161',
>   '749295052', '387823261', '387605479', '641687520', '641682562',
>   '594009615', '557270520', '313848522', '309700213', '284919779',
>   '215263233', '544345556', '544340954', '144661', '51773702',
>   '202957457', '202957451', '172051323'

I am sure I can convert from GI to accession, but it would be nice to avoid the additional step. What slice of magic am I missing?

Thank you in advance.

*especially since NCBI is phasing out GI numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking through the [docs for `esearch`](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/#chapter4.ESearch) on NCBI's website, there are only two `rettype`s available - `uilist`, which is the default XML format that you're getting currently (it's parsed into a dict by `Entrez.read()`), and `count`, which just displays the `Count` value (look at the complete contents of `result`, it's there), which I'm unclear on its exact meaning, as it doesn't represent the total number of items in `IdList`...

At any rate, `Entrez.esearch()` will take any value of `rettype` and `retmode` you like, but it only returns the `uilist` or `count` in `xml` or `json` mode - no accession IDs, no nothin'.

[`Entrez.efetch()`](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/#chapter4.EFetch) will pass you back [all sorts of cool stuff](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/table/chapter4.T._valid_values_of__retmode_and/?report=objectonly), depending on which DB you're querying. The downside, of course, is that you need to query by one or more IDs, not by a search string, so in order to get your accession IDs you'd need to run two queries:

```
search_phrase = "Escherichia coli[organism]) AND (complete genome[keyword])"
handle = Entrez.esearch(db="nuccore", term=search_phrase, retmax=100)
result = Entrez.read(handle)
handle.close()
fetch_handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nuccore", id=results["IdList"], rettype="acc", retmode="text")
acc_ids = [id.strip() for id in fetch_handle]
fetch_handle.close()
print(acc_ids)
```

gives

> ['HF572917.2', 'NZ_HF572917.1', 'NC_010558.1', 'NZ_HG941720.1', 'NZ_HG941719.1', 'NZ_HG941718.1', 'NC_017633.1', 'NC_022371.1', 'NC_022370.1', 'NC_011601.1', 'NZ_HG738867.1', 'NC_012892.2', 'NC_017626.1', 'HG941719.1', 'HG941718.1', 'HG941720.1', 'HG738867.1', 'AM946981.2', 'FN649414.1', 'FN554766.1', 'FM180568.1', 'HG428756.1', 'HG428755.1', 'M37402.1', 'AJ304858.2', 'FM206294.1', 'FM206293.1', 'AM886293.1']

So, I'm not terribly sure if I answered your question satisfactorily, but unfortunately I think the answer is "There is no magic."

Comment: I thought there must have been a parameter that I was missing, but yours is certainly an acceptable approach. It is working perfectly -- thank you very much.

Comment: @cer glad to help. I spent a lot of time looking through the docs and googling, because you would assume that there's a way to return accession IDs through `esearch`, but I just couldn't find anything. I'm glad this works for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Just found some documentation here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/#chapter4.ESearch

Looks like if you set 'idtype' to 'acc' in your Entrez.esearch parameters you can return a list of accession numbers directly without using a subsequent Entrez.efetch using the GI numbers from IdList.

This works for me:

```
search_phrase = "Humulus lupulus"
stream = Entrez.esearch(db="nuccore", idtype='acc', term=search_phrase, usehistory='y', retmax=10)
results = Entrez.read(stream)
ID = results['IdList']
for acc in ID:
    print(acc)
stream.close()
```